# How to convert UTC to CST timestamp by retaining the milliseconds in data in Hive

Tags: hive, timestamp, hiveql, unix-timestamp, milliseconds

I have a hive table in which the data with datatype timestamp is in UTC format. I have created a view on top of this table to convert `UTC` to `CST` with daylight savings. That conversion is working fine. But the data is missing milliseconds in it.

The below logic is used in view to convert UTC to CST

```
FROM_UTC_TIMESTAMP(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(added_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') * 1000, 'CST6CDT')
```

Please help me to convert `UTC` to `CST` including the milliseconds in timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

**unix_timestamp() function ignores milliseconds**. it returns seconds passed from unix epoch. Milliseconds are lost. For example:

```
 select FROM_UTC_TIMESTAMP(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2020-01-21 15:15:35.125', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') * 1000, 'CST6CDT');
```

returns:

```
2020-01-21 09:15:35
```

**If the timestamp is in the right format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'** (and in your example, according to the template, it does not require conversion), this works fine:

```
with s as (select '2020-01-21 15:15:35.125' as added_date) 

select FROM_UTC_TIMESTAMP(s.added_date, 'CST6CDT')  from s;
```

Result:

```
2020-01-21 09:15:35.125
```

**And if the timestamp is in the format which requires conversion**, the workaround is to extract milliseconds from original timestamp and add to the milliseconds you got after multiplying unix_timestamp by 1000:

```
with s as (select '2020-01-21 15:15:35.125' as added_date) 

select FROM_UTC_TIMESTAMP(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(s.added_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') * 1000+cast(split(added_date,'\\.')[1] as int), 'CST6CDT')  from s;
```

Result:

```
2020-01-21 09:15:35.125
```

**One more workaround** is to concatenate with milliseconds:

```
with s as (select '2020-01-21 15:15:35.125' as added_date) 

select concat_ws('.',cast(FROM_UTC_TIMESTAMP(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(s.added_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') * 1000, 'CST6CDT') as string),split(added_date,'\\.')[1]) from s;
```

Result:

```
2020-01-21 09:15:35.125
```